# Invalidate varnish by HTTP headers or by * in url

Tags: varnish, varnish-4

So I have some urls like this `www.example.com/userID/productID` this url sets this HTTP headers `X-Cache-Tags: product-productID, user-userID, product`

Now I want to purge all caches where `X-Cache-Tags` is `product-productID` or I want to purge all urls that are [www.example.com/*/productID](http://www.example.com/*/productID)

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the VCL code you need to make it happen:

```
vcl 4.0;

acl purge {
    "localhost";
    "192.168.55.0"/24;
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
        if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
            return(synth(405));
        }
        if(!req.http.x-invalidate-tag && !req.http.x-invalidate-pattern) {
            return(purge);
        }
        if(req.http.x-invalidate-tag) {
            ban("obj.http.X-Cache-Tags ~ " + req.http.x-invalidate-tag);
        } else {
            ban("obj.http.x-url ~ " + req.http.x-invalidate-pattern
            + " && obj.http.x-host == " + req.http.host);
        }
        return (synth(200,"Ban added"));
    }
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    set beresp.http.x-url = bereq.url;
    set beresp.http.x-host = bereq.http.host;
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    unset resp.http.x-url;
    unset resp.http.x-host;
}
```

There are 3 ways you can remove content from the cache using this VCL:

1. Purge an individual URL
2. Ban all objects that match a cache tag
3. Ban all objects where the URL matches a pattern

#### Purge URL

When a request with an approved client IP performs an `PURGE` request, only the exact URL is used to remove an object from cache:

```
curl -XPURGE http://example.com/20/100
```

#### Ban using cache tags

The following `curl` request will remove all objects from cache that have an `X-Cache-Tags` response header that contains the tag `product-10`:

```
curl -XPURGE -H "x-invalidate-tag: product-10" http://example.com/
```

#### Ban using URL pattern

The following `curl` request will remove all objects from cache where for a product `10`, for all users:

```
curl -XPURGE -H "x-invalidate-pattern: ^/[0-9]+/10/?$" http://example.com/
```

#### Conclusion

As long as your VCL is flexible enough, you can use all kinds of mechanisms and rules to invalidate the cache.

Please secure access to content invalidation via an ACL, as mentioned in the VCL example. You can also add extra protections such as password authentication or firewalling.